# Hudson + Custom Email

Tags: svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn, hudson, hudson-plugins

I am using Editable Email Notification plugin with Hudson. The version control tool used is SVN (Subversion). In the email extension plugin there is an option to send mail to "committers". If this option is enabled, it will fetch the user details from SVN and send mail to those people.

In our case SVN is configured with active directory(NT login) and hence hudson is trying to send mail to  NTLogin@domain.com which is not correct. I have a text file with NT Logins of all people and their E-Mail ids.

Is there any way I can configure Hudson to read this text file and send email to the actual email ID instead of NTLogin@domain.com.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default email suffix (the `@domain.com` part):

- Go to **Manage Hudson**
- Click **Configure System**
- Scroll down to **E-mail Notification**
- Change `Default user e-mail suffix` to whatever you need it to be, for example `@yourcompany.com`
- Click **Save**

This way, it will append `NTLogin` for each user with this suffix.

If your emails don't actually follow `NTLogin@yourcompany.com` standard, you can try to have Jenkins extract it from the AD information. Clear this `Default user e-mail suffix` field and leave it blank.

If that doesn't work (it depends on your AD configuration), you may need to overwrite the email address for each user individually:

- Click on the **People** link
- Select the user you want, then click **Configure**
- Manually enter the email address for that user that you want.
- Click **Save**

Note that for the user to appear in the People list, that user should be known to Hudson (i.e. either manually created in Hudson, or to have had committed something in the past that Hudson had checked out)

Comment: I think I can use the people link for this. But I have thousands of users to add. Any idea about the corresponding backend file will be of great helpful. :)

Comment: No, your only options are either per-user settings, or global `email suffix`. If the global email suffix is not good for you (i.e. your `NTLogin` differs from user's actual email alias), then try the option of setting `email suffix` to blank. It will try to extract user information from AD, and the AD usually has an entry for user's email alias (provided the AD is configured correctly). If your AD does not have email aliases configured... i don't know what would help you. There is a plugin to create email aliases using RegEx https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RegEx+Email+Plugin

Comment: Global email suffix will not work here. AD does not have proper email informations. Is adding the people and correcting the email ids in each configuration page work?

Comment: Yes, in your case you will have to update the email address for each user then. You can always ask the people themselves to login to their accounts and update their email (users have permissions to update their account info). While not 100% reliable, it would cover most of the people. You can also look into the possibility of setting up correct email aliases on the AD (it would help in more cases than just Jenkins), but that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks Slav.. But the users will get created under the option "Pepole" only if they do some updates in SVN and hudson checkouts the same. If some new user is updating a file, that user will be updated with the next build only. In that case email as part of that build will not reach him, unless he correct the email address. Is there any way i can create the users manually...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way to create users manually if they are authenticated off AD.